# Why is an + b = O(n^2)?

Tags: math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I need to prove that an + b = O(n<sup>2</sup>) using the formal definition of big-O notation. I have searched several textbooks I own on discrete mathematics as well as several online sources for any examples or theorems that are related to this proof, with no good results. I am not looking for a direct solution, but perhaps the right methods or paradigms to solve the proof.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you asking: prove O(an+b) = O(n^2) -- if so please edit question so its a bit easier to read

Comment: Hi just cuirous, isn't it O(n), because a and b are constant?

Comment: One of the reasons why `= O(...)` is a bad notation. `O(n^2)` is a set. `O(n)` is a strict subset of `O(n^2)`. If something is an element of `O(n)`, it is also an element of `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: n<sup>r</sup> ≤ n<sup>s</sup> for all n ≥ 1 if r ≤ s.  Therefore:

> an + b ≤ an<sup>2</sup> + bn<sup>2</sup> = (a + b)n<sup>2</sup> if n ≥ 1

From this, can you see what choice of n<sub>0</sub> and c you would pick to show that an + b ≤ cn<sup>2</sup> whenever n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>?  Can you see how you could also use this to prove that an + b = O(n)?

Hope this helps!